# Java Solaris NIO OP_CONNECT problem

Tags: java, sockets, solaris, nio

I have a Java client that connects to a C++ server using TCP Sockets using Java NIO.  This works under Linux, AIX and HP/UX but under Solaris the `OP_CONNECT` event never fires.

Further details:

- `Selector.select()` is returning 0, and the 'selected key set' is empty.
- The issue only occurs when connecting to the local machine (via loopback or ethernet interface), but works when connecting to a remote machine.
- I have confirmed the issue under two different Solaris 10 machines; a physical SPARC and virtual x64 (VMWare) using both JDK versions 1.6.0_21 and _26.

Here is some test code which demonstrates the issue:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class NioTest3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i, tcount = 1, open = 0;
        String[] addr = args[0].split(":");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(addr[1]);
        if (args.length == 2)
            tcount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        InetSocketAddress inetaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr[0], port);
        try
        {
            Selector selector = Selector.open();
            SocketChannel channel;
            for (i = 0; i < tcount; i++)
            {
                channel = SocketChannel.open();
                channel.configureBlocking(false);
                channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
                channel.connect(inetaddr);
            }
            open = tcount;
            while (open > 0)
            {
                int selected = selector.select();
                System.out.println("Selected=" + selected);
                Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext())
                {
                    SelectionKey key = it.next();
                    it.remove();
                    channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                    if (key.isConnectable())
                    {
                        System.out.println("isConnectable");
                        if (channel.finishConnect())
                        {
                            System.out.println(formatAddr(channel) + " connected");
                            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (key.isWritable())
                    {
                        System.out.println(formatAddr(channel) + " isWritable");
                        String message = formatAddr(channel) + " the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes());
                        channel.write(buffer);
                        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    }
                    else if (key.isReadable())
                    {
                        System.out.println(formatAddr(channel) + " isReadable");
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                        channel.read(buffer);
                        buffer.flip();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        String message = new String(bytes);
                        System.out.println(formatAddr(channel) + " read: '" + message + "'");
                        channel.close();
                        open--;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    static String formatAddr(SocketChannel channel)
    {
        return Integer.toString(channel.socket().getLocalPort());
    }
}
```

You can run this using the command line:

```
java -cp . NioTest3 <ipaddr>:<port> <num-connections>
```

Where port should be 7 if you are running against a real echo service; i.e.:

```
java -cp . NioTest3 127.0.0.1:7 5
```

If you cannot get a real echo service running then the source to one is [here](http://www.filesonic.com/file/1366967694/echoserver.c). Compile the echo server under Solaris with:

```
$ cc -o echoserver echoserver.c -lsocket -lnsl
```

and run it like this:

```
$ ./echoserver 8007 > out 2>&1 &
```

This has been reported to Sun as a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7063180).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked-around this bug using the following:

If `Selector.select()` returns 0 (and didn't timeout, if the timeout version was used) then:

1. Iterate over the keys registered with the selector via `selector.keys().iterator()` (remembering **not** to call `iterator.remove()`).
2. If `OP_CONNECT` interest has been set with the key then call `channel.finishConnect()` and do whatever would have been done if `isConnectable()` has returned `true`.

For example:

```
if (selected == 0 && elapsed < timeout)
{
    keyIter = selector.keys().iterator();
    while (keyIter.hasNext())
    {
        key = keyIter.next();
        if (key.isValid())
        {
            channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
            if (channel != null)
            {
                if ((key.interestOps() & SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT) != 0)
                {
                    if (channel.finishConnect())
                    {
                        key.interestOps(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has been reported to Sun as a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7063180).

Comment: The bug was closed as 'not an issue', for a reason that was already stated in my answer.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne That was back in 2012.  Why are you commenting about it now?

Comment: Because it's still true. If `select()` returns 0 it *is* a timeout, or a wakeup.

Answer (score 13):

Your bug report has been closed as 'not a bug', with an explanation. You are ignoring the result of `connect()`, which if true means that `OP_CONNECT` will never fire, because the channel is already connected. You only need the whole `OP_CONNECT/finishConnect()` megillah if it returns false. So you shouldn't even register `OP_CONNECT` unless `connect()` returns false, let alone register it before you've even called `connect().`

Further remarks:

Under the hood, `OP_CONNECT` and `OP_WRITE` are the same thing, which explains part of it.

As you have a single thread for this, the workaround would be to do the connect in blocking mode, then switch to non-blocking for the I/O.

Are you doing the select() *after* registering the channel with the `Selector`?

The correct way of handling non-blocking connect is as follows:

```
channel.configureBlocking(false);
if (!channel.connect(...))
{
    channel.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT, ...); // ... is the attachment, or absent
}
// else channel is connected, maybe register for OP_READ ...
// select() loop runs ...
// Process the ready keys ...
if (key.isConnectable())
{
  if (channel.finishConnect())
  {
     key.interestOps(0); // or SelectionKey.OP_READ or OP_WRITE, whatever is appropriate
  }
}
```

A few non-exhaustive comments after reviewing your extended code:

1. Closing a channel cancels the key. You don't need to do both.
2. The non-static `removeInterest()` method is incorrectly implemented.
3. `TYPE_DEREGISTER_OBJECT` also closes the channel. Not sure if that is what you really intended. I would have thought it should just cancel the key, and there should be a separate operation for closing the channel.
4. You have gone way overboard on the small methods and exception handling. `addInterest()` and `removeInterest()` are good examples. They catch exceptions, log them, then proceed as though the exception hadn't happened, when all they actually do is set or clear a bit: one line of code. And on top of that many of them have both static and non-static versions. Same goes for all the little methods that call `key.cancel()`, `channel.close()`, etc. There is no point to all this, it is just clocking up lines of code. It only adds obscurity and makes your code harder to understand. Just do the operation required inline and have a single catcher at the bottom of the select loop.
5. If `finishConnect()` returns false it isn't a connection failure, it just hasn't completed yet. If it throws an `Exception`, *that* is a connection failure.
6. You are registering for `OP_CONNECT` and `OP_READ` at the same time. This doesn't make sense, and it may cause problems. There is nothing to read until `OP_CONNECT` has fired. Just register for `OP_CONNECT` at first.
7. You are allocating a `ByteBuffer` per read. This is very wasteful. Use the same one for the life of the connection.
8. You are ignoring the result of `read()`. It can be zero. It can be -1, indicating EOS, on which you must close the channel. You are also assuming you will get an entire application message in a single read. You can't assume that. That's another reason why you should use a single `ByteBuffer` for the life of the connection.
9. You are ignoring the result of `write()`. It could be less than `buffer.remaining(`) was when you called it. It can be zero.
10. You could simplify this a lot by making the `NetSelectable` the key attachment. Then you could do away with several things, including for example the channel map, and the assert, because the channel of the key must always be equal to the channel of the attachment of the key.
11. I would also definitely move the `finishConnect()` code to the `NetSelector`, and have `connectEvent()` just be a success/failure notification. You don't want to spread this kind of stuff around. Do the same with `readEvent()`, i.e. do the read itself in `NetSelector`, with a buffer supplied by the `NetSelectable`, and just notify the `NetSelectable` of the read result: count or -1 or
    exception. Ditto on write: if the channel is writable, get something to write from the `NetSelectable`, write it in the NetSelector, and notify the result. You could have the notification callbacks return something to indicate what to do next, e.g. close the channel.

But really this is all five times as complex as it needs to be, and the fact that you have this bug proves it. Simplify your head.

Comment: Yes, the channel is registered with the `Selector` as soon as it's opened and interest in `OP_CONNECT` is set after the call to `connect` (else `ConnectionPendingException` is raised).  Blocking the connect would cause me problems - the connections happen at ad-hoc times and if it interferes with the I/O of other threads then that's bad.

Comment: @trojanfoe The channel needs to be registered and set to OP_CONNECT before the connect(), otherwise you can miss the event. ConnectPendingException can't possibly be thrown *before* you have called connect() - I do not understand. The reason for that exception is quite explicit in the Javadoc and this isn't it.

Comment: I have made that change and tested it under Linux (it works) but it doesn't fix the issue under Solaris.  I mentioned the wrong exception - it was NoConnectionPendingException but that is no longer happening so please ignore that.

Comment: @trojanfoe You'll have to post some code. I'll put the correct way to deal with it into my answer, barring typos.

Comment: @trojanfoe see my code. You need to take care of the possibility that finishConnect() returns false. Your echo code doesn't do that.

Comment: I have uploaded a proper test case that demonstrates the issue under Solaris.  If you are able to download it and run it yourself, then I would be grateful.

Comment: @trojanfoe see revised post above for some comments.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I will implement your suggestions, but you haven't told me why it works on 4 UNIX platforms (including Mac OS X) and not on Solaris.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work on Solaris. I imagine it is some thread timing thing you haven't taken account of in your over-complex code. Simplify it and you (a) may eliminate the problem and (b) will certainly be able to understand it more easily. I did all the above and removed 250 out of about 900 lines of code in NetSelector. That's rather a lot of fluff.

Comment: OK, as requested, a simplified test case has been given in my question; this contains no threading at all, but still demonstrates the issue, so the problem is definitely related to the Socket implementation under Solaris and not to complexity of code.  Please give it a try.