# Kafka Source - Understanding the semantics of Selector.poll()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, polling

I was looking into Kafka's network layer code have a few questions regarding the Selector
class, particularly how the poll() method is implemented. The poll() method goes something like this:

```
void poll(int timeout){
....
    /* check ready keys */
    long startSelect = time.nanoseconds();
    int readyKeys = select(timeout);
    long endSelect = time.nanoseconds();
    this.sensors.selectTime.record(endSelect - startSelect, time.milliseconds());

    if (readyKeys > 0 || !immediatelyConnectedKeys.isEmpty()) {
        pollSelectionKeys(this.nioSelector.selectedKeys(), false, endSelect);
        pollSelectionKeys(immediatelyConnectedKeys, true, endSelect);
    }

...
}
```

Is there a specific requirement because of which we call `pollSelectionKeys()` method first
for the keys returned by the `select()` method and then on the immediately connected keys? Is
it just for clarity that we perform these operations separately, or are there some specific
requirements involved?

Secondly, in the `pollSelectionKeys()` method, we have:

```
void pollSelectionKeys(Iterable<SelectionKey> selectionKeys,
                                       boolean isImmediatelyConnected,
                                       long currentTimeNanos){
...
    /* if channel is ready write to any sockets that have space in their buffer and for which
    we have data */
    if (channel.ready() && key.isWritable()) {
        Send send = channel.write();
        if (send != null) {
            this.completedSends.add(send);
            this.sensors.recordBytesSent(channel.id(), send.size());
        }
    }
...
}
```

From what I understand, we only ever write to a `KafkaChannel` when either it belonged to
the keySet we obtained from the earlier call to the `select()` method, or if the `KafkaChannel`
associated with one of the `immediatelyConnectedKeys`. My question is, why do we go about the
business of writing to the `KafkaChannels` this way? More specifically, we don't we just iterate
over all the `KafkaChannels` that have been connected, and write to them if they have a `Send`
object associated with them? In this way, we write to the `KafkaChannel` as soon as we can,
without waiting for it to belong to the `immediatelyConnectedKeys` or `readyKeys`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the **connect** method of [Selector](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/9ed8bf273c6ee5569ed68b71782ec7ab947f9c93/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/network/Selector.java) class (relevant portion below)

```
 connected = socketChannel.connect(address);
..............................
................................

 SelectionKey key = socketChannel.register(nioSelector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
```

As per the doc explanation of NIO [SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress)) connect

> If this channel is in non-blocking mode then an invocation of this
>   method initiates a non-blocking connection operation. If the
>   connection is established immediately, as can happen with a local
>   connection, then this method returns true. Otherwise this method
>   returns false and the connection operation must later be completed by
>   invoking the finishConnect method.

So a typical workflow of interaction is as follows ( explained very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347014/java-nio-connect-to-socket))

If you're connecting in non-blocking mode you should:

> - register the channel for OP_CONNECT
> - when it fires call finishConnect()
> - if that returns true, deregister OP_CONNECT and register OP_READ or OP_WRITE depending on what you want to do next
> - if it returns false, do nothing, keep selecting
> - if either connect() or finishConnect() throws an exception, close the channel and try again or forget about it or tell the user or
>     whatever is appropriate.
>
> If you don't want to do anything until the channel connects, do the
>   connect in blocking mode and go into non-blocking mode when the
>   connect succeeds.

This connect method may **immediately** connect as in case of local connection and may not trigger OP_CONNECT event which is registered for this connection socketChannel ( few lines after the connect call) , so when using typical java NIO register code, we may miss it. We need to call finishConnect eventually on such channels (see second bullet point in workflow). So we add such channel key to  another Set `immediatelyConnectedKeys` so that they can be processed too later or else we would miss them completely.

```
 if (readyKeys > 0 || !immediatelyConnectedKeys.isEmpty()) {
            pollSelectionKeys(this.nioSelector.selectedKeys(), false, endSelect);
            pollSelectionKeys(immediatelyConnectedKeys, true, endSelect);
        }
```

And later in `pollSelectionKeys` method ( note the use of `finishConnect` which is a call to [finishConnect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#finishConnect()) to the underlying [SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)

```
 /* complete any connections that have finished their handshake (either normally or immediately) */
                if (isImmediatelyConnected || key.isConnectable()) {
                    if (channel.finishConnect()) {
.........................
.........................
```

All in all the Kafka code looks like standard NIO stuff going on unless there is more which Kafka team can explain.Further good reads on this subject can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354755/at-what-point-during-java-nio-socket-on-the-server-or-client-end-is-the-socket-c). An interesting misunderstanding related to this ( [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540346/java-solaris-nio-op-connect-problem) filing and eventual rejection by JDK team) can be found [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7063180)

For the second part of question you probably are asking about the below code. Why two separate calls for keys

```
if (readyKeys > 0 || !immediatelyConnectedKeys.isEmpty()) {
            pollSelectionKeys(this.nioSelector.selectedKeys(), false, endSelect);
            pollSelectionKeys(immediatelyConnectedKeys, true, endSelect);
        }
```

See we now have two set of keys maintained .Although there is a overall keys view is provided by `selector.keys()` but the key set is not directly modifiable so it's kind of read only view. The key in this key-set is removed only after it has been cancelled and its channel has been deregistered. So typically `selector.selectedKeys()` is used to access the ready channel. Also `selector.selectedKeys()` will obviously not return the keys from `immediatelyConnectedKeys`. The usual pattern of processing over these keys obtained from selector.selectedKeys() is to iterate over set , test what event (acceptable,connectable,readable/writable) the channel represented by 
key is ready for , do your stuff and then remove it from the set. This removal part is quite necessary.The Selector does not remove the SelectionKey instances from the selected key set itself. You have to do this, when you are done processing the channel.
The next time the channel becomes "ready" the Selector will add it to the selected key set again. So that's the reason both are processed and the method `pollSelectionKeys` is  designed to take care of both.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Do you have any responses for the second question above?

Comment: I added to what I think about the second question.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP connection is not available until the I/O connection is complete